# MFMailComposeViewController Force actual size on image attachment

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on an app that allows a user to email an image using MFMailComposeViewController.  The attached image is 1200 x 1800 and it is imperative that the image size not change.

With large images, MFMailComposeViewController presents the user with an action sheet giving them the option to scale the image down when 'Send' is pressed (see screenshot).  I'd prefer this action sheet not be displayed and to force the actual size of the image attached.

Any suggestions appreciated!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

MFMailComposeViewController is a class whose behavior we are not supposed to alter, according to Apple's guidelines. So, better stick to the default behavior so as not to run into problems when you submit the App for review. However, there is a hack you can do : when a user selects any other option, other than what you want, show a message saying that the actual size is what will be attached as that's the App's behavior and that his/her choice will be ignored.

Comment: Appreciate your response, Jean.  Please elaborate on how one would determine which selection the user made.  Perhaps I've overlooked it, but I didn't see anything in the `MFMailComposeViewController` delegation methods.

Comment: -1 for two weeks with no elaboration.  I don't think what you've suggested is actually possible.